# 2008 Audi A4 Quattro (3.2L) Ipod dock and music

Tags: audio, audi

Couple questions about music in my 2008 Audi A4 Quattro (3.2L).

I used to have a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini. I used to use a bluetooth media streaming app to play music and GPS navigation via the bluetooth in the car. But since I got the LG Nexus 5 I am not able to use any bluetooth streaming apps to do that now. Any ideas what happened?

Also, I have the Ipod doc connector in the glove compartment, but I do not have Ipod, and I wanted to use my phone's AUX (headphone) jack to play music and everything else. Can anyone recommend a cable that will work for me? I am asking because I have seen some cables on Amazon, and in the pictures they have the built-in screen it says "Audi Music Interface". I do not have that. I have only CD and MP3. The MP3 refers to the two SDCARDs slots I have behind the screen.

Comment: I don't have a clue about the LG Nexus 5 situation. As for the other ... you could get [this adapter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/280984270467?lpid=82).

Comment: On second thought, did you go through the process to connect the LG to your stereo? You have to go through the process of re-associating the new phone to the stereo before you can stream using bluetooth. Maybe this was obvious to you and you did it, but sometimes it's the little things we forget to do.

Comment: I am able to talk over the phone via the bluetooth. So the phone is paired with the car, each time i get into the car. Or are you talking about something else?

Comment: Pairing with the car is what I was suggesting. Is there a separate pairing for your radio? I would doubt it, but you never know. Since your phone is paired with the car, though, I'd suggest you use something like I posted in the first comment. If you don't want to go that way, I'd wonder if it's something with the phone and not the car. You may ask your question over on the electronics SE site.

Comment: And looking through the available SE sites, it doesn't look as though there is one for questions on electronics as such.

Comment: You can post your answer, so I will at least choose it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to ensure your phone is paired with your car. If that is good, you could use [this type of adapter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/280984270467?lpid=82) to attach it directly from your 3.5mm port on your phone to the iPod connector in your glove box.